# Debugging a Scala project (IntelliJ Idea 12 and sbt)

Tags: debugging, scala, sbt

I've seen a few articles describing how to debug Scala applications, but nevertheless I want to ask it again due to the reason that all those articles are outdated and all things change very quickly in Scala world.

I use IntelliJ Idea 12 + sbt (not a plugin, a plugin doesn't work for some reason).

So how do I do that **nowadays**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMO, you are best off keeping SBT and Intellij separate, as they are two different concerns. One is for building, and the other is for developing.

Here are the steps that I typically go through to get a solid Scala/Intellij development environment up and running for a new Scala project.

- Step 1: Install [Scala Intellij Plugin](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/)
- Step 2: Create a simple sbt project - [details here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Hello.html)
- Step 3: Add the fantastic [sbt-idea](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea) plugin to your sbt config
- Step 4: `sbt gen-idea`
- Step 5: Open project in Intellij 12
- Enjoy debugging, syntax highlighting, code assist and all of the other nice IJ features.

On the sbt side, I typically keep a terminal open, with sbt running so that I can rapidly test things outside the context of Intellij.

HTH

Comment: `Enjoy debugging, syntax highlighting, code assist and all of the other nice IJ features.` -- how? how do I debug? I already have had all of these.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question?  You debug the same way you would debug a standard Java application. [Details here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/debugging.html)

Comment: I can't setup scala compiler. If I had a java application, I would be very I guess. As for scala, there are many errors and difficulties. Do you know how to setup scala debugger? For example, Compiler-> Scala compiler gives me "Nothing to show here in external build mode".

Comment: Thats because they moved the configuration to under Project Settings -> Facets -> Scala.  That is where you configure the Scala compiler.

Comment: I still can't do that. this is how it looks like http://makescreen.ru/i/fe5b7cc6cbbd6b7719a3bc0608a587.jpg But nonetheless, it doesn't see the external dependencies (like import org.json4s._), likewise when I compile it from sbt command line, everything works well -- it compiles.

Comment: and also, how should "run configuration" look like?

Comment: would you mind having a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418047/cant-debug-a-scala-application-in-intellij-sbt-idea-plugin