# Can't debug a Scala application in IntelliJ + sbt-idea-plugin

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm developing a Scala application using IntelliJ Idea 12, sbt and [sbt-idea plugin](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea). I generated all necessary files by saying "`gen-idea`" and everything goes well -- I was able to compile the sources in command line in sbt as well in IntelliJ Idea 12 itself using menu Build->Make Project.

Here is my main class (`Application.scala`)

```
object Application extends App {
  val a = 12345
  println("application entry point 1235")
}
```

I have a breakpoint at `val a = 12345`.

1) There were other errors before, but now says "`Module is not specified`". How do I solve this?

I'll be posting updates since there would be other errors as my gut tells me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To debug just like to run, you need to create a run configuration (menu Run -> Edit Configurations). If you haven't done yet, you need to add an `Application` entry with the + button.

Not only do you need to specify the main class, but also which "module" that class belongs to. By default, "Use classpath of module" will be empty. Here in the popup menu, you need to select the main module (not the one ending in "-build"). After you choose that and close with "Ok", it should work.

[image]

---

Although not necessary, I also recommend to use sbt for building instead of "Make". In the configuration in the "Before launch" part, select "Make" and click on "-", then click on "+" and choose sbt -> test:products.

**Edit**: [Here is the reference](https://github.com/orfjackal/idea-sbt-plugin/wiki) for the SBT plugin for IntelliJ.

Comment: O my God, I can't believe I made it run! There might be other issues, though, but for now it's perfectly fine.

Comment: I can't run worksheet, it says `Failed to initialize compiler: class scala.reflect.BeanInfo not found.
  ** Note that as of 2.8 scala does not assume use of the java classpath.
  ** For the old behavior pass -usejavacp to scala, or if using a Settings
  ** object programatically, settings.usejavacp.value = true.`, even though I made exactly the same configuration for it as for Application.

Comment: No problem here with worksheet... Perhaps open a new question for that. Which Scala version are you using in your project—2.10?

Comment: I will. By the way, how do make Idea to use sbt rather then its own compiler to compile a project using Build->Make Project (Ctrl+F9)?

Comment: You need to have the SBT plugin installed (that's not the sbt-idea plugin for sbt; that's a plugin for IDEA—Settings -> plugins). You get a new tab at the bottom of the screen "SBT Console". That lets you execute `~compile`. In run config, you need to change from "Make" to "sbt", then running or debugging the project will use sbt for compilation.

Comment: `In run config, you need to change from "Make" to "sbt",` -- where do I find this exactly? It's set to "sbt -> test:products." as you said before.

Comment: Yes exactly. That means you are already using sbt. The "Build" button in the toolbar somehow doesn't care about the run config, it will always use "Make" if I'm not mistaken. So just don't press that button :) If you run or debug, it will use sbt. I recommend to keep the sbt console open with `~compile` or `~test:compile`. Whenever you hit Cmd-S, sbt will automatically pick up the changes and recompile the necessary files, while you keep working.

Comment: I asked about the button, though. ` Cmd-S` -- what is it? I'm on Linux.

Comment: On OS X: Cmd-S = "save" currently open text documents. That will make sbt notice changes. On other OS it might be Ctrl-S.